# Simple @Configurable with modern spring-boot + gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

My goal is to get a bare bones aspectj+spring aop setup such that I can use @Configurable on one class. One additional restriction is that it needs to use load-time weaving as Lombok doesn't work with CTW.

The good news: I have it working!

The bad news: The console is flooded with `[Xlint:cantFindType]` errors. See results section below.

## The Environment

I have a single class annotated with `@Configurable`. It is a class used by and instantiated by Jackson, hence the need for AOP. It's not very interesting so I won't show it here. It's just a normal class with the single annotation of Configurable, and an `@Autowired` bean inside.

### SpringBootApplication

My Application class has the usual annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class MyApplication {
```

### build.gradle

My build.gradle has all the usual suspects. Sample:

```
configurations {
    springinstrument
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE')
..snip..
    runtime('org.springframework:spring-instrument:4.+')
    springinstrument "org.springframework:spring-instrument:4.+"
    runtime configurations.springinstrument.dependencies
}

test.doFirst {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.springinstrument.asPath}"
}
```

### jvm args

I am running a JUnit test with the following args (via Intellij's run config)

```
-ea
-javaagent:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-instrument/4.3.3.RELEASE/5db399fa5546172b9c107817b4abaae6b379bb8c/spring-instrument-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
```

### aop.xml

I have a `src/main/resources/META-INF/aop.xml` containing:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
        <weaver options="-Xreweavable -showWeaveInfo">
        <!-- only weave classes with @Configurable interface -->
        <include within="@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable */>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

However, my suspicion is that this file is not being picked up. It doesn't matter what I put in the file, the results are always the same. Even if I put random non-valid XML.

### The Test

The junit test is a simple Jackson serialize-deserialize test using the `@Configurable` annotated class.

The test class has the annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

## The Results

### When running a junit test via Intellij -> It Works, but..

The LTW is actual working and my test is passing when run via Intellij with the jvm args above.

However the boot time of the app is *significantly longer* and the log is flooded with `Xlint:cantFindType` errors

Example:

```
2016-11-07 19:28:21.944  INFO 45213 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
when weaving type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.AccessLogHandler
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.AccessLogHandler
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.AccessLogHandler
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
.. many more.. all in the org.springframework.boot package
```

### When running a test via gradle command line -> works, sort of.

<del>When I run the test with `gradle test --tests *MyTestClass`, the test fails because of a NullPointerException on.. guess what, the `@Autowired` bean I'm expecting to be injected automatically.</del>

I got it working with gradle test config, huzzah! I've updated the configuration above. But.. it suffers from the same problem as running it in my IDE: `the Xlint:cantFindType`

---

So the issues:

1. <del>The gradle configuration is wrong, so running the app via gradle fails. How do I fix the gradle config?</del>
2. The `Xlint:cantFindType` errors. Is the aop.xml not being picked up? **How to resolve this?**

I have yet to find a simple spring-boot+gradle+ @Configurable sample that uses aop.xml

Comment: Did you try using `-javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar` instead of `-javaagent:spring-instrument.jar`?

Comment: I did actually, I had it working first with aspectjweaver, and I encountered the same problem. I switched it to spring-instrument thinking that might solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem, and it's rather embarrassing.

1. It was due to the fact that the `aop.xml` wasn't being picked up.
2. The file wasn't being detected because it was in a directory named `META_INF/` on the class path, not `META-INF/`. That's a pretty important difference.

Anyways, I've updated the question with the minimal configuration needed to get `@Configurable` working with a modern spring-boot and gradle setup with load time weaving for Lombok support. Hopefully it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Super helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem, can't get it to work, can you post your app source somewhere maybe ?

Comment: ok, I fixed it with :
1. my aop.xml was in root of jar instead of META-INF
2. added aspectjwaver to javaagents